# Material 3 in Angular 17?

Tags: angular, material-ui

I've read all the docs (https://github.com/material-components/material-web/blob/main/docs/quick-start.md)

I still can work out how to use this in my Angular 17 project.

I do this, `npm install @material/web`

Then import a component, like this,

```
import {MdOutlinedTextField} from '@material/web/textfield/outlined-text-field.js'
```

After that I try import MdOutlinedTextField, into the component, but cannot , as it complains that the import is for standalone components only

Then including this,
`<md-outlined-text-field label="Label" value="Value"></md-outlined-text-field>`, in the html, gives this:

```
Application bundle generation failed. [0.389 seconds]
⠸ Changes detected. Rebuilding...✘ [ERROR] TS-992012: Component imports must be standalone components, directives, pipes, or must be NgModules. [plugin angular-compiler]

src/app/2. contract-module/edit-tabs/personal-information-edit/personal-information-edit.component.ts:27:120:
  27 │ ...t, FieldEntryComponent, ReactiveFormsModule, MdOutlinedTextField],
```

Sorry, I'm a beginner : (

Maybe others have been able to get through this?

Comment: The owns authors of angular/web suggest @material/angular for angular, see the [readme](https://github.com/material-components/material-web#readme)

Comment: Material 3 should be supported soon with Angular Material but you'll have to wait meanwhile.

Comment: Yes, I gave up on the Material Web quickstart guide, as it wasn't step by step explained - at least for beginners. I'm using Angular Material, which works great : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material 3 support for Angular, has been [released in v17.2](https://blog.angular.io/material-3-experimental-support-in-angular-17-2-8e681dde650e).

You can now use design tokens, customization becomes scary eazy !

```
<mat-checkbox class="scary-setting">Delete my account</mat-checkbox>

.scary-setting {
  // No need to target any internal checkbox selectors! 
  - mdc-checkbox-unselected-hover-state-layer-color: red;
  - mdc-checkbox-unselected-hover-icon-color: red;
}
```